# How to configure multiple site maps in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, sitemap

I want to configure multiple sitemaps due to the size of sitemaps in my application.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET works with XML files for site navigation, by default it uses Web.sitemap that describes the hierarchy of the web site. However we can configure it to use more than one site-map fiile or site-map provider for navigation structure.

Eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode  title="Home Page"  description="">
   <siteMapNode title="Category 1"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode  title="Category 2" description="">
      <siteMapNode  title="Sub Category 1" description=""/>
      <siteMapNode  title="Sub Category 2" description=""/>
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode siteMapFile="child.sitemap" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

The child map could be the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode  title="Child Category 1"  description="">
    <siteMapNode title="Child Sub Category 1"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode  title="Child Sub Category 2"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode  title=""  description="" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

The Result will be

```
Home Page
  Category 1
  Category 2
    Sub Category 1
    Sub Category 2
  Child Category 1
    Child Sub Category 1
    Child Sub Category 2
```

The below line links the style:

```
<siteMapNode siteMapFile="MySiteMap.sitemap" />
```

Comment: Can we link to a custom site-map provider from a parent site map?

Comment: Yes you can do it using siteMapNode in your XML as: <siteMapNode provider="YourTextSiteMapProvider" />